# Play midi from Linux with old synths

Tags: midi

I have an Ubuntu Linux Laptop with USB ports.

I have an old Yamaha Sy22 from the 90's

I just want to edit music via a sequencer and play the music via the synth. No sound card or whatever alike. I just want my synth play notes.

The synth output will be sent to a Zoom R20.

What software/driver I need on the laptop? (Ubuntu 20.04).

What sequencer to install?

What hardware converter can I buy to connect midi cable to USB port.

Thank you

Comment: aplay or sox commands